# Errors running "nordvpn connect" on Wake from Suspend

Tags: linux, ubuntu, suspend, sleep

I'm running Pop!_OS, a Ubuntu based OS, and I want to run `nordvpn disconnect` before suspend and `nordvpn connect` after suspend. I'm using code from [this arch linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Hooks_in_.2Fusr.2Flib.2Fsystemd.2Fsystem-sleep) and can't get the `nordvpn connect`/`nordvpn disconnect` commands to run on system wake. I added the file `99nordvpn-reload` to `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` and made it executable with `sudo chmod a+x 99nordvpn-reload`. The code in that file is:

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    nordvpn disconnect
    ;;
  post/*)
    nordvpn connect
    ;;
esac
```

waking from sleep, running `journalctl -u systemd-suspend.service` shows:

`Jun 13 22:08:38 pop-os [4520]: /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/99nordvpn-reload failed with exit status 1.`

I have also tried running the command as a local user with:

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    sudo -u $USER nordvpn disconnect
    ;;
  post/*)
    sudo -u $USER nordvpn connect
    ;;
esac
```

but `$USER` is replaced with the output from `echo $USER`. However, I get the same error message as before. I'm assuming this error has something to do with the `nordvpn` package being installed locally or my `$USER`, hence the attempt at executing the command with `sudo -u $USER`.

Based on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/661747), I also attempted creating the globally executable file `/usr/local/bin/nordvpn-reload` with contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

nordvpn disconnect;nordvpn connect
```

and changing the contents of `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/99nordvpn-reload` to:

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    exit 0
    ;;
  post/*)
    /usr/local/bin/nordvpn-reload
    ;;
esac
```

but once again, I get the same error as always. Any suggestions/advice/further reading would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something similar on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and for me it worked with the script at `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/nordvpn-reload`:

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1 in
  pre)
    nordvpn disconnect
    ;;

  post)
    nordvpn connect
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to change the `pre)` line from [@moritz-shroeder's response](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/619072/552505) to make sure nordvpn is actually shut down:

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1 in
  pre)
    pkill -9 nordvpn
    ;;

  post)
    nordvpn connect
    ;;
esac
```

As you can see, I'm using `pkill` here, with the signal `9`. This tells nordvpn to actually KILL its process. For some reason, a simple `disconnect` was not enough in my case.

You can learn more on `pkill` [here](https://linuxize.com/post/pkill-command-in-linux/)